# How to define a new hooked arrow?

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I want to use the following hooked arrow instead of usual one:

[image]

where its tail is math command `subset`. But zooming further to this one (image from Lee smooth manifolds, p. 563) it reveals that it has been assembled in awkward way (see below):
[image]

> How can I have such arrow in `tikz-cd` or inside math formulas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? `tikz-cd` allows you to use glyphs for arrow tips. (I had to define a slightly wider version in order to avoid the symbol from being clipped.)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=xGlyph,
  cache=false,
  bending mode=none,
  parameters={\tikzcd@glyph@len,\tikzcd@glyph@shorten},
  setup code={%
    \pgfarrowssettipend{\tikzcd@glyph@len\advance\pgf@x by\tikzcd@glyph@shorten}},
  defaults={
    glyph axis=axis_height,
    glyph length=+1.55ex,
    glyph shorten=+-0.1ex},
  drawing code={%
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{+-1.5ex}}{\pgfpoint{+\tikzcd@glyph@len}{+3ex}}%
    \pgfusepathqclip%
    \pgftransformxshift{+\tikzcd@glyph@len}%
    \pgftransformyshift{+-\tikzcd@glyph@axis}%
    \pgftext[right,base]{\tikzcd@glyph}}}
\makeatother    
\tikzset{
supset/.tip={xGlyph[glyph math command=supset,
    glyph axis=5.2pt]},
}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd} 
 A \arrow[supset-latex,d]\\
 B \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maximal zoom under preview on a Mac:

[image]

Alternatively you can use `\pgfdeclarearrow` to declare the arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = shook,
  parameters = {\the\pgfarrowlength,\the\pgfarrowwidth},
  setup code = {
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{.01\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.1\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
% The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowlength}{0pt} 
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{-\pgfarrowwidth} 
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\pgfarrowlength and \pgfarrowwidth/2}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{-\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \pgfusepathqstroke
},
  defaults = { length = 4pt,width=8pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [shook-latex] (0,0) -- (0,-2);
    \draw [{shook[length=3pt]}-latex] (1,0) -- (1,-2);
    \draw [thick,{shook[length=3pt,width=7pt]}-latex] (2,0) -- (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1.5. Thanks @Schrödinger's cat. But same problem again when I zooming it in (slightly better)!!! or maybe it is because of my Screen resolution?

Comment: @C.F.G One has to be extremely lucky to have the line width of the glyph coincide with the line width of pgf. However, I added a second version in which I draw the hook, so the line width matches perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot (=mc^2).

Comment: @C.F.G It might also be a viewer issue. On preview the glyph proposal seems to be fine, on acroread one can see a very tiny corner at magnification 1600%.

Comment: I prefer the first one of your answer, because I can change the size of `supset` by `glyph length=1.5ex`. What about the second code?

Comment: `glyph length=1.5ex` change the size in both dim x and y in properly way.

Comment: @C.F.G I added a version in which you can change both the width and the length.

Comment: Thanks. In first code, why I can't use other directions? e.g. `r`, `l`.

Comment: @C.F.G You can. Try `\[\begin{tikzcd} 
 A \arrow[supset-latex,d] \arrow[supset-latex,r] & C\\
 B  & D\\
\end{tikzcd}\]`.

Comment: The second code output seems that is equal to usual hook. isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G I made a mistake with the glyph, didn't realize its lower part got clipped. Fixed it.