# How to fix the bad output of custom arrow in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Please see the following GIF file that shows the output of some arrows in my computer: (arrow in first pdf is from `TikZ-cd doc.pdf` and second pdf generated by [@Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703) in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514451/108724))
[image]

and its screenshot:
[image]

> What is the problem really? it is because of my PC graphic card or `TikZ` can't determine the line width in this case? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The second part of the answer you link to does not have the problem, I think, because it does not use glyphs. As you point out, this seems to be a generic problem with glyph arrows, and *might* be a viewer problem. (+1)

Comment: Excuse me but you can tell me know how to create this gif?

Comment: @justonly: this app for windows os: https://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: Which viewer do you use to get this? According to what I find, different viewers appear to yield different results. This is unfortunately something that pops up here and there, and there seems not to be a once-and-for-all fix.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat reader.

Comment: I also suspect that a viewer-problem might be the underlying cause. I had something similar with Okular before. Is the imperfection persistent on higher zoom-levels (after it occured first)? Because from your gif I'd say that at one level it's there and at another one it's not. This indicates a viewer-problem to me. You might also try what happens when printing this. If the error is visible in printed form, we know it's indeed a problem of the PDF and not just with the rendering on screen

Comment: Unfortunately I have not printer. If it is the viewer-problem, then why the looped arrow as shown in GIF doesn't have that problem?

Comment: Interestingly, according to what I find the problem seems to depend on the angle. Can you please see what happens on your machine if you use the diagram `\[\begin{tikzcd} 
 A \arrow[supset-latex,r] \arrow[supset-latex,d] \arrow[supset-latex,dr] & B\\
 C & D \\
\end{tikzcd}\]` instead? According to what I find, the problem depends on the slope, which might be why it does not show up for the looped arrow.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Yes. It works perfectly for `dr` only.

Comment: But why your screenshots in your answer to my previous post differ from mine?

Comment: I was using preview on a Mac to produce these screen shots. Different OS, different viewer. Apparently there are issues for horizontal and vertical arrows. Possibly the loop arrow also will have issues if it is not bent.

Comment: So the problem is about TikZ behavior?

Comment: According to what I find, `\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
math to/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]},
loop/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft, swap]},
weird/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=Rrightarrow, glyph length=1.5ex]},
pi/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=pi, glyph length=1.5ex, glyph axis=0pt]},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=rule_thickness]
\draw[loop-math to] (0,2) to (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` also has the problem.

Comment: Yes,, exactly. Can you fix this problem until next week?

Comment: @C.F.G I am not sure if anyone but the developers of the viewers can fix the issue. There are tons of such issues and they have been reported regardless of Ti*k*Z. If the developers of the viewers do not fix it, the only thing that one can do is to define arrows without glyphs. The lower code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514451/108724 does not have the problem, right? So one can design similar arrows for all other cases.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I saw some bad outputs for [tag:mathtools] package. see [screenshot of this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6796) for similar issue. I saw similar problem about clipped big norm sign but now I can't find it. as you mentioned `\xrightarrow` also have same problem. Isn't these  because of bad calculating or my machine unit measurement or maybe latex internal issues?

Comment: @C.F.G I believe it is a viewer issue and not a LaTeX issue. As your animation shows, sometimes one line seems to be thinner at the right side and in another magnification the issue is on the left side. I am not at all an expert, but could imagine that the viewers have some fast but less precise routines that specialize on vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: So let try it. Please download [Tikz-cd-doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) and look at the looped and other arrows on page 15. What you see?

Comment: Your animation shows what one sees under Acrobat Reader, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. Acrobat Reader on windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat), This is a viewer issue. The following GIF shows the same pdf file in 4 different viewer on same OS and machine: (Adobe Acrobat reader DC, Adobe Reader DC, Sumatra PDF, Chrome Browser resp.)

[image]